# Need unique values of a range in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I need to list unique values of 12 columns in a different sheet columns.

Like sheet 1 has A column.

I need to list the unique values of all 12 columns in Sheet 2 to Sheet1 A column.

Like:

[image]

want to list like this:

[image: want to list like this]

Comment: Will always the values be single letter / word?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Unique Values From a Matrix](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/52619/88163)

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and maybe [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 4):

Quick and dirty way :

```
=UNIQUE(ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(A1:F12&""),""))))
```

[(Source : organizing google-sheets data range into single column)](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115358/organizing-google-sheets-data-range-into-single-column)
However, care must be taken not to exceed 50k characters when using `concatenate`. If the case arises, simply break the formula into several pieces or use arrays.

```
=unique({A1:A10;B1:B10;C1:C10})
```

---

Edit : I have just learned that this problem can now be solved in an even simpler way. `=unique(flatten(A1:F12))`

Comment: The quick and dirty way looks slower (more characters to type) than the other way :D

Comment: Yeah, I didn't give it a second thought, that was pretty dumb :o. But I still think solution 1 is easier because there's only an unique range to type. I'm confused and lost :)

Comment: Love the simplicity of your EDIT here. Thanks

Comment: Do understand that FLATTEN is a not-yet-official Google Sheets function. As such, using it comes with the risk that Google may — or may not — choose to add it to the official functionality.